# Unable to create app groups in gnome shell

Tags: gnome, 15.04

Can anyone please guide me, how to make app groups in GNOME Shell?

I have tried

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell app-folder-categories "['Utilities', 'Sundry', 'Games' ]"
```

but it did not worked. Edited the `or.gnome.shell.desktop.xml` file, still did not worked.

How should I proceed?

Answer (score 2):

*This is no longer possible in this way, see below for the new way.*

Therefore, the usual steps do not work anymore:

- Open `dconf-editor`
- Navigate to org/gnome/shell
- Locate the entry `app-folder-categories` and add or remove categories

Another proof:

```bash
$ gsettings set org.gnome.shell app-folder-categories "['Utilities', 'Sundry', 'Games' ]"
No such key 'app-folder-categories'
```

---

The currently working way

- Create a folder <kbd>Audio</kbd>

  ```bash
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders folder-children "['Audio']"
  ```
- Set the name `Audio`

  ```bash
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Audio/ name 'Audio'
  ```
- Add some apps

  ```bash
  gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.app-folders.folder:/org/gnome/desktop/app-folders/folders/Audio/ apps "['audacious.desktop', 'brasero.desktop']"
  ```

<sub>More examples and category based folders [here](https://developer.gnome.org/AppFolders/)</sub>

Comment: Hi A.B.,

Under dconf-editor, the entry app-folder-categories is missing. Manually edited org.gnome.shell.desktop.xml and run this command. No error message, but the apps did not grouped as per the category.

Regards / Pallab

Answer (score 1):

The location has apparently changed, it resides presently now in `dconf-editor` under:

- org → gnome → desktop → app-folders

Also, you can now create new groups from gnome-software natively, the UI now has options for making new groups and add applications to them. I personally just add groups from gnome-software and then change values in dconf to add applications.