# How to create folder in Gnome 3.14?

Tags: gnome, directory

In gnome 3.14, through dConf Editor, **app-folder-configuration** it disappeared !

*How do I create folders ?*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to create app groups in gnome shell](http://askubuntu.com/questions/614844/unable-to-create-app-groups-in-gnome-shell)

Answer (score 0):

This feature will be available only in the 3.10 version. All you can do now is to play a bit with dconf-editor.

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell app-folder-categories "['Utilities', 'Sundry', 'Games' ]"
```

More info you will find [here](http://worldofgnome.org/how-to-create-custom-appfolders-in-gnome-shell-3-8/).

Comment: Sorry but in org.gnome.shell, "app-folder-categories" isn't present.